# How to get id and name value of button on click event in ionic 2 angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a button

```
<button ion-button icon-left name="0x10000011 (click)="AppService.sendNotify($event)" id="0x10000011" value=1>
  <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
  CAM Icon
</button>
```

When I click on it, I want to get the `id` attribute in my service `sendNotify` function.

```
public sendNotify(data) {
  var method = 'SCAN_BUTTON';
  var name = data.target.name;
  var id = data.target.id;
  var value = data.target.value - 0;
  console.log("#$#$%$%^$%^#$%^#$%",method, name, value);
}
```

Here I am not getting the button `id` and `name`. Instead

```
#$#$%$%^$%^#$%^#$% SCAN_BUTTON undefined NaN.
```

Can anyone help me to find my error?

Comment: why not just send your name/id as parameters of the function?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are considering an ionic component [ion-button](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#buttons-in-components) to be a basic html `button` tag.

It is actually an angular component. Check [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/components/button/button.ts).

Its inner html looks like:

```
<span class="button-inner">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</span>
<div class="button-effect"></div>
```

depending on *where in the button you click* it sends the tag's id and name with the event.The click area could be `button` tag *or* `span`.

You should simply send the value as a parameter.

```
<button ion-button icon-left name="0x10000011" (click)="AppService.sendNotify($event,'0x10000011','0x10000011')" id="0x10000011" value=1>
  <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
  CAM Icon
</button>
```

[**A plunker to try**](https://plnkr.co/edit/buAfDitKNDOL3iYQeWYo?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

you can get the values using the below code

```
<button id="ar" name="some" (click)="clicked($event)"> CLICK ME </button>


clicked(event){
    console.log(event.srcElement.id)
    console.log(event.srcElement.name)

  }
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fn2alTNzuPIUK5yfX15k?p=preview)**

Comment: I tried to use secElement but i'm getting the same result as before. Is it because of Ionic?

Comment: what are you passing to the method as parameter `$event`?

Comment: @Araving the same code i am using in my angular 2 web app and it works there. there the event carry button id name and value. its not workin gin ionic app.

Comment: Not "secElement" try "srcElement" as @Aravind suggested. That should work. If not try consoling the value you get from the passed parameter and update it in your question so that it will be easy for people to help you get solved the issue

Comment: for me i had to use event.srcElement.attributes.name.nodeValue

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good in general, I also suggest to use the target instead of the srcElement.

In your code you just miss to close the name attribute, try to change it to this:

```
<button ion-button icon-left name="0x10000011" (click)="AppService.sendNotify($event)" id="0x10000011" value=1>
  <ion-icon name="camera"></ion-icon>
  CAM Icon
</button>
```

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. its my typo and it doesn't work

Comment: If it still does not work, could you please provide a Plunker?

Comment: I am using ionic how can i create a plunker for that?

Comment: Sure, you could use [this starter](http://embed.plnkr.co/ONkXIK0ByvBwWeAfgMcD/), but probably you should upgrade the dependency versions in nsystemjs.config.js.